# Implicit conversion of std::pair to reference on second element

Tags: c++11, stl

I have an object `it` of type `std::pair<Key, T>` and want to define an implicit conversion to a reference to the second element.

```
T& convert(std::pair<Key, T>& it) { return it.second; }
T const& convert(std::pair<Key, T> const& it) { return it.second; }
```

Can this be done implicitly in the definition of `class T`? Ideally, I want to pass `it` to a function that expects `T&`.

Background: Iterators over an associative container (`std::unordered_map`) dereference to an object of type `std::pair<Key, T>`. I would like to have a syntax where I can switch easily between a sequential and an associative container (`std::vector` vs. `std::unordered map`). Consider this code:

```
std::vector<T> container;
// std::unordered_map<Key, T> container;
void func(T&);

for (auto& it : container) {
    func(it);
}
```

Comment: Different issue, but a variable named `it` strongly suggests an iterator when I read the code, and yours is not.  Recommend finding a better name for your elements (key-value pairs) of the map.

Comment: BTW this really seems like an XY problem.  Instead of messing up the pairs, why not just run your foreach over the values?  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html and syntax looks like `for (auto& v : container | boost::adaptors::map_values)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing at this Boost trick, I didn't know it. Does it also work if container is a std::vector? Concerning the name of the variable: `it` is a dereferenced iterator, not so far from what the name suggests. Definitely it is not the value type of the container, this is what I wanted to emphasise.

Comment: Unfortunately according to the terminology the C++ standard has chosen, `pair<const TKey, TValue>` is the `value_type` of the unordered map.  `key_type` is obvious, and "`mapped_type`" is the name given to `TValue`.  Of course, we know what you mean.  There's also a function version of the adaptor, usage looks like `for (auto& v : boost::adaptors::values(container))` and it should be quite straightforward to write overloads which return the collection itself for vector inputs and the result of `boost::adaptors::values(container)` for map types.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be done implicitly in the definition of class T?

Yes and no.

The yes part: You create a converting constructor.

```
class T 
{
  public: 
    // Use a delegating constructor to implement shi
    template <typename Key> T(std::pair<Key, T> const& item) : T(item.second) {}
};
```

The no part: You won't be able to get a non-`const` reference. The converting constructor will create a temporary, which will always result in a `const` reference.

---

IMO, a better solution will be to overload `func`

```
void func(T&);

template <typename Key>
void func(std::pair<Key, T>& item)
{
    func(item.second);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea with the overload, I'll go for that although I have a number of these functions. The first plan with the converting constructor does not work since I need to change the data of the elements.